# What is the purpose of the contacts under the sticker on the underside of this microSD card?

Tags: sd-card, micro-sd-card

Many (most?) microSDs have a sticker on the bottom:

[image]

I peeled one off, and revealed several small copper contacts beneath it:

[image]

What is the purpose of these?

Comment: My guess is they are for factory programming via pogo pins

Comment: programming, testing, status detection, fast-write(?)... depends on what the factory considered reasonable for factory use.